# how to determine signal strength of a pcm sample? in terms of power

Tags: signal-processing, signals, pcm, signal-strength

I read that signal power = signal * signal. What is that? what is signal? how do we obtain it? I'm programming in C(if that's necessary to post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signal is the *amplitude* of whatever input source you have sampled. E.g. for audio you might have 16 bit signed samples, and +32767 might represent say +1.0 V analogue and -32768 would be -1.0 V analogue. (The relationship between digital sample value and whatever analogue quantity you are sampling is usually linear, which makes life simple.)

To calculate the *power* of a signal you would measure the mean square value, e.g.

```
double sum_sq = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    sum_sq += (double)sample[i] * (double)sample[i];
}
double power = sum_sq / (double)N;
```

Comment: You mean the power of N samples(which are same as signals)?

Comment: And in the case of the signal samples not being centered around the value 0 (e.g. with an unsigned sample type), you would need to calculate (or guess) the arithmetic mean first and instead of squaring `sample[i]`, square `(sample[i]-mean)`.

Comment: why is the arithmetic mean necessary?

Comment: @Namratha: yes, this is the power over a window of N samples.

Comment: @Namratha: in most cases you shouldn't need to subtract the mean (i.e. DC component) - it will usually be quite small for most real-world signals, such as audio.

Comment: Subtracting the DC component isn't necessarily the right thing to do. It's effectively a high-pass filter. If N is short, you could be subtracting a lot of energy you're interested in.

Comment: @John: indeed - it really depends on the nature of the signal and whether you are interested in measuring energy at DC. For audio you probably don't want the DC component (which will be small anyway), but for other types of signal it may be important.

Comment: @Namratha: that depends on the input signal range of your A-D input system and what this signal actually represents. The digital representation itself has no implicit units - it all depends on the *calibration* of your system (signal source, analogue processing, A-D input range, etc). (Power itself is measured in Watts, of course.)